# Get lowest price on sum of combinations in given array

Tags: php, algorithm, multidimensional-array, combinations

This code is working fine when the array length is 8 or 10 only. When we are checking this same code for more than 10 array length.it get loading not showing the results.

How do reduce my code. If you have algorithm please share. Please help me.

This program working flow:

```
$allowed_per_room_accommodation =[2,3,6,5,3,5,2,5,4];
$allowed_per_room_price =[10,30,60,40,30,50,20,60,80];
$search_accommodation = 10;
```

i am get subsets = [5,5],[5,3,2],[6,4],[6,2,2],[5,2,3],[3,2,5]

Show lowest price room and then equal of 10 accommodation; output like as `[5,3,2];`

```
<?php 
    $dp=array(array());
    $GLOBALS['final']=[];
    $GLOBALS['room_key']=[];
    function display($v,$room_key) 
    {   
        $GLOBALS['final'][] = $v;
        $GLOBALS['room_key'][] = $room_key;
    }

    function printSubsetsRec($arr, $i, $sum, $p,$dp,$room_key='') 
    { 

        // If we reached end and sum is non-zero. We print 
        // p[] only if arr[0] is equal to sun OR dp[0][sum] 
        // is true. 
        if ($i == 0 && $sum != 0 && $dp[0][$sum]) { 
            array_push($p,$arr[$i]);
            array_push($room_key,$i);
            display($p,$room_key);
            return $p; 
        } 

        // If $sum becomes 0 
        if ($i == 0 && $sum == 0) { 
            display($p,$room_key);
            return $p; 
        } 

        // If given sum can be achieved after ignoring 
        // current element. 
        if (isset($dp[$i-1][$sum])) { 
            // Create a new vector to store path 

            // if(!is_array(@$b))
            // $b = array();
            $b = $p;
            printSubsetsRec($arr, $i-1, $sum, $b,$dp,$room_key); 
        } 


        // If given $sum can be achieved after considering 
        // current element. 
        if ($sum >= $arr[$i] && isset($dp[$i-1][$sum-$arr[$i]]))
        { 
            if(!is_array($p))
                $p = array();
            if(!is_array($room_key))
                $room_key = array();
            array_push($p,$arr[$i]);
            array_push($room_key,$i);
            printSubsetsRec($arr, $i-1, $sum-$arr[$i], $p,$dp,$room_key); 
        } 
    } 


    // Prints all subsets of arr[0..n-1] with sum 0. 
    function printAllSubsets($arr, $n, $sum,$get=[]) 
    { 
        if ($n == 0 || $sum < 0) 
            return; 
        // Sum 0 can always be achieved with 0 elements 
        // $dp = new bool*[$n]; 
        $dp = array(); 
        for ($i=0; $i<$n; ++$i) 
        { 
            // $dp[$i][$sum + 1]=true;
            $dp[$i][0] = true; 
        } 
        // Sum arr[0] can be achieved with single element 
        if ($arr[0] <= $sum) 
            $dp[0][$arr[0]] = true; 
        // Fill rest of the entries in dp[][] 
        for ($i = 1; $i < $n; ++$i) {
            for ($j = 0; $j < $sum + 1; ++$j) {
                // echo $i.'d'.$j.'.ds';
                $dp[$i][$j] = ($arr[$i] <= $j) ? (isset($dp[$i-1][$j])?$dp[$i-1][$j]:false) | (isset($dp[$i-1][$j-$arr[$i]])?($dp[$i-1][$j-$arr[$i]]):false) : (isset($dp[$i - 1][$j])?($dp[$i - 1][$j]):false);
            }
        }
        if (isset($dp[$n-1][$sum]) == false) { 
            return "There are no subsets with";  
        } 

        $p; 
        printSubsetsRec($arr, $n-1, $sum, $p='',$dp); 
    } 

    $blockSize = array('2','3','6','5','3','5','2','5','4');
    $blockvalue = array('10','30','60','40','30','50','20','60','80');
    $blockname = array("map","compass","water","sandwich","glucose","tin","banana","apple","cheese");
    $processSize = 10; 
    $m = count($blockSize); 
    $n = count($processSize); 
    // sum of sets in array
    printAllSubsets($blockSize, $m, $processSize);
    $final_subset_room = '';
    $final_set_room_keys = '';
    $final_set_room =[];
    if($GLOBALS['room_key']){
        foreach ($GLOBALS['room_key'] as $set_rooms_key => $set_rooms) {
            $tot = 0;
            foreach ($set_rooms as  $set_rooms) {
                $tot += $blockvalue[$set_rooms];
            }
            $final_set_room[$set_rooms_key] = $tot;
        }
    asort($final_set_room);
    $final_set_room_first_key = key($final_set_room);
    $final_all_room['set_room_keys'] = $GLOBALS['room_key'][$final_set_room_first_key];
    $final_all_room_price['set_room_price'] = $final_set_room[$final_set_room_first_key];
    }
    if(isset($final_all_room_price)){
        asort($final_all_room_price);
        $final_all_room_first_key = key($final_all_room_price);
        foreach ($final_all_room['set_room_keys'] as  $key_room) {
            echo $blockname[$key_room].'---'. $blockvalue[$key_room]; 
            echo '<br>';
        }
    }
    else
        echo 'No Results';
?>
```

Comment: Problem is not stated properly. What does output means?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your task is, given a list rooms, each with the amount of people it can accommodate and the price, to accommodate 10 people (or any other quantity).

This problem is similar to [0-1 knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0/1_knapsack_problem) which is solvable in polynomial time. In knapsack problem one aims to maximize the price, here we aim to minimize it. Another thing that is different from classic knapsack problem is that full room cost is charged even if the room is not completely occupied. It may reduce the effectiveness of the algorithm proposed at Wikipedia. Anyway, the implementation isn't going to be straightforward if you have never worked with dynamic programming before.

If you want to know more, [CLRS book on algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) discusses dynamic programming in Chapter 15, and knapsack problem in Chapter 16. In the latter chapter they also prove that 0-1 knapsack problem doesn't have trivial greedy solution.

Comment: As stated, there is no need in DP, greedy approach is enough (perhaps I don't recognize full problem properly)

Comment: @MBo you indeed can try to use greedy approach, e. g. sort rooms by cost per person and take rooms until everybody is accommodated, but this approach would ask for a proof of correctness. On the other hand I feel (I haven't tried) that it would be relatively easy to come up with a counterexample where a greedy algorithm will fail to yield the cheapest solution.

Comment: Forn now this problem is equivalent to "fractional/continuous knapsack" problem, not to `0/1` one (0/1 arises if we have **non-breakable groups** of people)

Comment: @MBo yes, this is exactly what I've been saying. Although nothing stops one from applying the solution for the fractional problem to a slight variation of 0/1 problem, but I doubt it will work.

Comment: Again - this is not 0/1 problem. Imagine 0/1 problem with gold/silver etc pieces of integer weight. If we can cut these pieces into 1-unit bits, problem becomes continuous - we just fill knapsack with max possible quantity of golden bits, then silver etc.

Comment: @MBo this point of view indeed has a potential to make the solution easier. My only concern here is that "cutting in 1 unit bits" doesn't entirely work for rooms - as soon as at least one person is accommodated in the room, full price of the room is added to the cost. E. g. two people, two single rooms $2/night, one 6 person room $6/night. "Dollars per person" is better for 6 person room, but two travelers are better stay in two single rooms. That being said, it now doesn't look as a classic 0/1 knapsack to me, yes.

Comment: Aha, now I see what you do mean! In this case - yes, continuous approach is not feasible.

Comment: I've checked the Knapsack problem and it takes more time to run my given input. I'm going to apply this case in Search page. So, can you please give me solution for this?